# How can I auto run the USBs files when it's plugged into my Chromebook?

Tags: files, usb, usb-drive, chrome-book, autostart

Auto running the file with a ".inf" is not working.

Comment: A very similar question was asked a while back but it did not have any accepted answer. The [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511306/chromeos-autorun-script-located-on-a-usb-drive) indicate that this cannot be easily done and possibly should not be enabled.

Comment: This was a very common thing to do in the days where computers where frequently getting infected with viruses. In this case correlation is causation. Consider having a script that resides on the chromebook, that runs when it detects an appropriate USB device.